# Logical Functions in Excel for aggregate data

Tags: excel-formula, logical-operators

In MS Excel, I am trying to write an aggregate function that counts the number of entries in a data table that meets a set of requirements.

I have tried using the AND(), OR() operators, but they only return a single value even when I input an array.

```
AND(1={1,1},1={1,1}) returns TRUE, instead of {TRUE, TRUE}
```

I have also tried using * as AND and + as OR, but for some reason this is what I get.

```
1={1;1}*1={1;1} returns {FALSE;FALSE} when I am expecting a {TRUE;TRUE}
```

However, when I put it all together, it works except when (TRUE + TRUE) * TRUE, it evaluates into FALSE instead of TRUE. These are the functions I am using below and their expected results. (header is row 0)

```
count - {sum(IF( (A1:A5=1 + B1:B5=1)*C1:C5=1 , 1, 0))} = 2
sum - {sum(IF( (A1:A5=1 + B1:B5=1)*C1:C5=1 , D1:D5, 0))} = 7
min - {min(IF( (A1:A5=1 + B1:B5=1)*C1:C5=1 , D1:D5, 9999999))} = 3
max - {max(IF( (A1:A5=1 + B1:B5=1)*C1:C5=1 , D1:D5, 0))} = 4 

A   B   C   D   
1   1   1   3   
1   0   1   4   
0   0   0   5  
0   0   1   6   
1   1   0   7
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and the expected result? There may be a simpler way to get what you want.

Comment: If you wrap the other in sum: `=SUM((1={1;1})*(1={1;1}))` and enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter then you will get 2.  You have to tell the formula what you want to do with the array.  BTW your other formula does not need the IF `=SUM(((A1:A5=1)+(B1:B5=1))*(C1:C5=1))`

Comment: See edits above

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it works in the agg functions. Do you know why it returns {FALSE, FALSE} when you highlight and hit F9? Seems weird to not return the correct values.  Also, if you remove the IF, then if A and B are both true, then it will count as 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

If you array enter then it does return an array, but you need to array enter over many cells.

For example: Highlight a range 2 high and 2 wide.  In the formula box put:

```
=(1={1,0})*(1={0;1})
```

and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  You will return an array of values:

[image]

By adding the SUM to the outside we are returning that array to the sum:

```
=SUM((1={1,0})*(1={0;1}))
```

Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter and you will get the sum of the array or `1`

[image]

If you want to display the array, one must array enter the formula over many cells, otherwise the display will only be the upper left value of the array.

Comment: =(1={1,0})*(1={0;1}) is just for test using F9 to calculate the value. I know you cannot display an array in a single cell; I am using agg functions, but I want to see what array I am inputting first

Comment: okay with hitting F9 I get `={0,0;1,0}` which is correct, BTW you get {FALSE,FALSE} on `1={1;1}*1={1;1}` because you  are missing the `()` around the groups so it solves in the correct order, `=(1={1;1})*(1={1;1})` will resolve to `{1,1}` when you hit F9.

Comment: ahh youre right. that fixes everything. basically i need parenthesis around each logical expression. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If our data is like:

[image]

So we want to count rows where **either** *A* or *B* or both are 1 **and** *C* is a one.

*(the 12 yellow rows)*

We can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A28)+(B1:B28)<>0)*(C1:C28))
```

[image]

Comment: I need to do other agg functions such as min, max, and sum. are there alternatives for those too? For example, there are values in columns D and E, and I want to get the sum of column D for all rows highlighted

Comment: @J.Doe  You would have to customize the function to match your logical needs...............sadly this is **not** as user-friendly as typical SQL syntax.

Comment: yeah i think the if functions is the best way to do this, with the columns a-c as the conditions and d as the results